# what are private keys (essentially) how can i make them using any given data?

Tags: private-key, encoding

private keys decode pub keys so how can they reveal other things?
can i reveal a web address from a private key?

I should be able to unpack anything from a private key seen as I can unpack something that can read/wrire decoide/encode

right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin private keys (secp256k1) are just a random 256bits "number" (256 random zero and ones), or say 32byte random data. The only constraints are, that the random number must be between 0x1 and 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD.

You can calculate the public key from your private key but not vice versa (it's not practical possible).

With "revealing a webaddress" you probably mean encryption. You can use Bitcoin private keys with available schemes (Ex. diffie hellman) to derive a symmetric encryption key (ex. AES256) and encrypt data for a particular receiver.

Answer (score 1):

> right?!

Wrong. I think you have misunderstood what a private key is.

Bitcoin's private keys are part of a pair of keys that are used for [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). The private key is randomly generated data, which you need to keep secret. The only thing it can "unlock" is something that was "locked" with the corresponding public key (which is used to generate a bitcoin address).

When somebody sends you bitcoin, you can think of it as them unlocking it with their private key, and then locking it with your public key (address). You can then unlock it with your private key when you want to spend it.